# navigationItem.backBarButtonItem not working? Why is the previous menu still showing as the button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

Trying to customize my back button in a drilldown navigation controller.

On my one view controller I have an *Add* button where the code programatically generates a new `UIViewController`:

```
- (void)add:(id)sender 
{
    MyAddViewController *addController = [[MyAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyAddViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addController animated:YES];

    [addController release];
}
```

This works and when I click the add button it drills down into the new view. Inside the `viewDidLoad` method of `MyAddViewController.m` I have:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```

But this isn't working. The back button in the navigation controller remains the **title** of the previous view's controller on the stack. It seems that line does nothing. Did I miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will only work on each child after the viewController that has `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 59):

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is for the back button that appears on the view pushed by the view controller. So you need to move that line to the previous view controller.

Comment: How do you assign the action to be performed on the pushed view before returning back to previous view Controller.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do it using the backBarButtonItem. To do that you need to replace the leftBarButtonItem and assign an action to it.

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 14):

You're confusing the `backBarButtonItem` and the `leftBarButtonItem`.  From the [`UINavigationItem` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) on `backBarButtonItem`:

> When this item is the back item of the
>   navigation bar—when it is the next
>   item below the top item—it may be
>   represented as a back button on the
>   navigation bar. Use this property to
>   specify the back button. The target
>   and action of the back bar button item
>   you set should be nil. The default
>   value is a bar button item displaying
>   the navigation item’s title.

So, if you were to change:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```

To:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```

I believe you would get the desired effect.

Comment: ...except for not being a 'proper back button', that is, it will be missing the arrow shape.

Comment: tyvm +1 - I just lost an hour trying to assign to backBarButtonItem when leftBarButtonItem was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

You can't replace the `backBarButtonItem`, but you can use the `leftBarButtonItem` to override it. But to get the new button to perform operate the same as the back button, you do need to set the target and action of the new button something like:

```
- (void)dismissMyView {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"Quit" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
        target:self action:@selector(dismissMyView)];
}
```

Comment: Except that it won't look like the back button (arrow shaped button)

Answer (score 1):

If ViewController A push ViewController B meanwhile we want to set the back bar button tittle, we should set "self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = ..".if it was set in ViewController B, it will not work as we want.