# UINavigationCotroller backBarButtonItem with other target than self

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, action, target, backbarbuttonitem

I am trying to change the action executed by pressing the backBarButtonItem of a Navigation Controller.
I know that i have to edit the backBarButtonItem before the next view (on which the button with custom behavior should appear) is pushed. So in the previous ViewController i added the following code, to push via segue:

```
#pragma mark - segue methods

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SettingsToProfile"]) {
        MyProfileViewController* myprofileVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        myprofileVC.myProfile = myProfile;
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings_" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:myprofileVC action:@selector(popTOSettingsViewController:)];
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    }
}
```

The title "Settings_" gets displayed correctly, but "target: myprofileVC action:@selector(popTOSettingsViewController:)" doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Background:

MyProfileViewController is a View, where the user can edit his/her own information. Whenever the backbarbutton is clicked, i want to check if something in the GUI has been changed by the user. If thats the case, a UIAlterView should ask the user, if he/she wants to save the changing. I tried to work it out with, viewWillDissappear, but the AlterView gets displayed in the next ViewController (and program crashes, if i click on the alterViewButtons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can change the target of a `backBarButtonItem`. How about `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` instead? There's a discussion at [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem not working ?? Why is the previous menu still showing as the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964276/self-navigationitem-backbarbuttonitem-not-working-why-is-the-previous-menu-st) that may be relevant.

Comment: I had it working with a leftBarButtonItem, but i am quite uncomfortable to change the appearance of it to a back button. I am just wondering, why the action (on other target) is not working.

Comment: The system does not use the target and selector you set for a backBarButtonItem. Someone else had the same problem at http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/297620-overriding-target-and-action-of-backbarbuttonitem.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, so way to go with leftBarButton :)