# action of UIBarbuttonItem not called ios

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to call the `UIBarButtonItem` when the back button of that controller is pressed.This is my code.I have put the initialization in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` but the method is not being called.

```
UIBarButtonItem *exampleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:(@selector(backToViewController:))];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = exampleButton;

-(void)backToViewController:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender
 {
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: Does the button show up correctly? Give the button an actual title so you can see it.

Comment: You could also call self.navgiationController popToRootViewController in viewWillDisappear. That would do the same.

Comment: Set your `exampleButton` as leftBarButtonItem.

Comment: The `backBarButtonItem` of a view controller is *not* shown in the view controller itself, it is shown in any view controller that is *on top of it* on the stack. This is because the back button usually shows the title of the *previous* view.

Comment: @keithbhunter i tried that the title shows up in the next controller for some reason

Comment: @soldiershin Check out [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964276/self-navigationitem-backbarbuttonitem-not-working-why-is-the-previous-menu-st).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT will not add `backBarButtonItem` with your line as :

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = exampleButton;
```

You have to Provide `leftbarbutton` as

```
UIBarButtonItem *exampleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"  " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:(@selector(backToViewController:))];
// As you are going with  "  ", there is no text, that means you have to click at left side randomly, to get affect.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = exampleButton;
```

**Update 1**

You can provide Custom button with Image created by you, as you want,

```
UIButton *barCutomBtn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[barCutomBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[barCutomBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backToViewController:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *exampleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:barCutomBtn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = exampleButton;
```

Comment: Yes this worked.Also can you tell me where can i find the default white back arrow in ios?

Comment: Please check update 1 from the answer, you need to create that image as you want.  With that image you can create new custom button as as you it with barbutton.